# MySql throws error Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve values from 3 table where i am getting error "Sub query returns more than 1 row " .

My concept is to retrieve all the post where i have to calculate the sum of votes from ttpostvotes table with respect to each post and if provided userid is voted for the that post then it will shows the post count like 1 or -1.

My query is as below:

```
SELECT r.PostId, r.`Post`,r.PostTime, coalesce(x.Votes, 0) as Votes , 
(Select Votes From `ttpostvotes` where UserId=30 and x.PostId=r.PostId ) as IsUservoted, 
(Select Count(*) From ttreply where PostId=r.PostId ) AS ReplyCount FROM `ttpost` r 
left join ( SELECT PostId, sum(Votes) as Votes FROM `ttpostvotes` GROUP BY PostId ) x ON
 x.PostId = r.PostId WHERE r.OffensiveCount<3 and r.SpamCount<5 and r.OtherCount<7 and r.`PeekId`=101 ORDER BY `r`.`PostTime` DESC
```

The 3 tables are like as below:
ttpost

[image: ttpost table structure]

ttpostvotes

[image: ttpostvotes]

ttreply

[image: ttreply]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `select`:

```
SELECT r.PostId, r.`Post`,r.PostTime, coalesce(x.Votes, 0) as Votes, 
       (Select Votes From `ttpostvotes` where UserId = 30 and x.PostId = r.PostId
       ) as IsUservoted, 
       (Select Count(*) From ttreply where PostId=r.PostId ) AS ReplyCount
```

The first subquery has no aggregation, so I suppose a user could vote more than once for a post.  This will fix the syntax error:

```
SELECT r.PostId, r.`Post`,r.PostTime, coalesce(x.Votes, 0) as Votes, 
       (Select SUM(Votes) From `ttpostvotes` where UserId = 30 and x.PostId = r.PostId
       ) as IsUservoted, 
       (Select Count(*) From ttreply where PostId = r.PostId ) AS ReplyCount
```

Whether it does what you want is a different question.

Note:  if you want your original query to work, you should define a unique constraint/index on `ttpostvotes`:

```
create unique index unq_ttpostvotes_userid_postid on ttpostvotes(userid, postid);
```